# Structure group of tangent bundle of Riemannian manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

In the article "Spin structures on manifolds" by J Milnor, the author begins as follows -

> Let $M$ be an oriented, Riemannian manifold. Then the tangent bundle of $M$ has the rotation group $SO(n)$ as structural group.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me where I could find a proof of this fact (or give me hints to prove it myself). Google didn't help much.

EDIT : Definition of Oriented manifold being used -

A smooth manifold $M$ is oriented if it admits an orientable atlas. That is an atlas whose all transition functions have positive Jacobian determinant.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you already know?  For example, do you already know that a vector bundle is orientable iff the structure group reduces from $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ to $Gl^+(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: The Jacobian of the coordinate transformation is an element of the structure group of the tangent bundle, so saying "transition functions have positive Jacobian determinant" is precisely the same as saying "structure group reduces to $Gl^+(n,\mathbb{R})$.  In other words, one equivalent version as to what Milnor is claiming is that on an oriented Riemannian manifold, there is an open cover for which all transition functions have Jacobians in $SO(n)$.

Comment: I just realized that what I said is the same as saying that the structure group of the tangent bundle of $M$ reduces to $GL^+(n,\mathbb R)$. How do I go from there to $SO(n)$?

Comment: This is turning out to be harder than I was suspecting.  In particular, when I wrote "one equivalent version..." above - I don't know how to prove its equivalent.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: If I understood you correctly, you claimed that on an oriented Riemannian manifold, there should be a covering by _coordinate charts_ whose transition functions have Jacobians in $SO(n)$. This is certainly not true, unless the metric is flat.

Comment: @Jack:  That, indeed, is what I was claiming.  Your comment explains why I was having so much trouble proving it!  Would you know where a proof of your claim can be found?  (I am aware of the fact that one can find a coordinate chart whose coordinate vector fields form an orthonormal basis at every point iff the manifold is locally flat, but what I was trying to prove seems a bit weaker.  Of course, if both coordinate vector fields are each orthonormal, then of course the transition map must be orthogonal, but...(continued)

Comment: it seems a priori possible that the transition map can be orthogonal even if the two coordinate vector fields are not orthonormal at each point.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: if you can find a covering by coordinate charts so that the Jacobians are all orthogonal, then you can _define_ a Riemannian metric by using the Euclidean inner product in each such chart. The compatibility condition ensures that the different definitions agree where they overlap. And this metric will be flat. Since many manifolds do not admit flat Riemannian metrics, they do not admit such coverings.

Comment: @Jack:  Of course.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E\to M$ is a rank-$k$ vector bundle, a ***reduction of the structure group of $\boldsymbol E$*** to a subgroup $G\subset GL(k,\mathbb R)$ is a covering of $M$ by local trivializations of $E$ such that the transition functions are of the form $(x,v) \mapsto (x,\tau(x)v)$, where $\tau$ takes its values in $G$.

Thus a reduction of the structure group of $TM$ to $SO(n)$ is a covering by *local frames* (NOT necessarily frames arising from coordinate charts) such that the change-of-frame matrix takes its values in $SO(n)$.

If $M$ is an oriented Riemannian manifold, you just take a covering by oriented orthonormal frames, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I understand the change of frame matrix takes values in $GL^+(n,\mathbb R)$. Why is it $SO(n)$? I understand why the determinant of this matrix should be positive (follows from the definition) but  not why it should be $+1$

Comment: Since all of the local frames are orthonormal, the change-of-frame matrix always takes values in $O(n)$. Since they are all positively oriented, the change-of-frame matrix takes values in $GL^+(n,\mathbb R)$. Now use the fact that $GL^+(n,\mathbb R) \cap O(n) = SO(n)$.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand how we get an orthonormal frame when the manifold is oriented. In general the tangent bundle of a manifold has structure group $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ right? If it oriented then I understand that the structure group reduces to $GL^+(n,\mathbb R)$. I don't understand where $O(n)$ comes from.